# Is $M^{-1} = \frac{1}{4} (M +3I)$? yes/ No

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is the following  statement True/false ?

> Let $M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &-1& 1\\2 &1 &4 \\-2 &1 &-4 \end{bmatrix}$ then  $M^{-1} = \frac{1}{4} (M +3I)$

**My attempt** : I think this statement is  true  because $1$ is an eigenvalue of $M$. Also, the  minimal polynomial of $M$ is $(x-1)(x+4)$.

Comment: the minimal polynomial: $(x-1)^2(x+4)$

Comment: yes, it is the minimal polynomial as well

Comment: Have you tried to verify $MM^{-1}=M^{-1}M=I$?

Comment: okay @CroCo  No, I didn't use this logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polynomial $$P(\lambda)=(\lambda-1)(\lambda+4)$$
is **not** the minimal polynomial of $M$.

A quick calculation shows that

$$(M-I_3)(M+4I_3)\neq 0$$
from which we find
$$M^2+3M-4I_{3}\neq 0\implies M^{-1}\neq \frac{1}{4}(M+3I_3)$$

**Remark**

Thanks to [CroCo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/103120/croco) and [Ted Shifrin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/71348/ted-shifrin)'s kind comments, I based my previous answer on OP's assumptions.

Comment: Isn't the characteristic polynomial of degree $3$ for this matrix?

Comment: @UmeshShankar I meant minimal. Thanks !

Comment: But $M^{-1}M\neq I$.

Comment: I've tried yours, I got $M^{-1}M\neq I$.

Comment: This is incorrect. Try calculating $M^2+3M-4I$. In fact, $1$ is an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity $1$, not $2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Fixed, thanks !

Comment: Basing an answer on the OP's assumptions does not often lead to a good answer.

Comment: @TedShifrin Absolutely! My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation of $M$ is
$$
p(\lambda) = \lambda^3 + 2\lambda^2-7\lambda + 4 
$$
Using [Cayley–Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), we get
$$
\begin{align}
M^3 + 2M^2-7M + 4I = 0 \implies M^{-1}=(-1/4)\Big( M^2 + 2M -7I\Big).
\end{align}
$$
Indeed, $MM^{-1}=M^{-1}M=I$.

Comment: The downvotes are not clear to me.

Comment: This is actually correct. The claim below about the minimal polynomial of $M$ is, in fact, incorrect.